# Pop up message on selectindexchanged in vb

Tags: vb.net, dropdownlistfor

I was wondering how can I display a pop up warning message every time the selected item in dropdown list has changed. I've managed to get it working , but the message will unfortunately also pop up when loading the form as in some cases the default value has already been set and is not empty. So far i have this:

```
Private Sub cboNew_DropDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   cboNew.SelectedIndexChanged

    If cboNew.SelectedItem = "%" Then
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format(" You Selected = " & cboNew.SelectedItem, MessageBoxButtons.OK))
    End If

    If cboNew.SelectedItem = "Value" Then
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format(" You Selected = " & cboNew.SelectedItem, MessageBoxButtons.OK))
    End If

    If cboNew.SelectedItem = "REVOKE" Then
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format(" You Selected = " & cboNew.SelectedItem, MessageBoxButtons.OK))
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: remove the Handles clause and use AddHandler in FormLoad to avoid getting the event while the form is created

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The mistake is in this statement  `MessageBox.Show(` change this as  `msgbox()` then your code will be like the following:

```
  Private Sub cboNew_DropDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles cboNew.SelectedIndexChanged

            If cboNew.SelectedItem = "%" Then
                MsgBox(String.Format(" You Selected = " & cboNew.SelectedItem, MessageBoxButtons.OK))
            End If

            If cboNew.SelectedItem = "Value" Then
                MsgBox(String.Format(" You Selected = " & cboNew.SelectedItem, MessageBoxButtons.OK))
            End If

            If cboNew.SelectedItem = "REVOKE" Then
                MsgBox(String.Format(" You Selected = " & cboNew.SelectedItem, MessageBoxButtons.OK))
            End If
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime it's hard to determine where the error came from. You could add a boolean flag to help you out.

```
Private _isLoading As Boolean = False

Private Sub YourLoadingSub
    _isLoading = True
    ' Do your loading code
    _isLoading = False
End Sub

Private Sub cboNew_DropDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   cboNew.SelectedIndexChanged

    If Not _isLoading  Then
        ' Show message box
    End If

End Sub
```

An other option is to remove the event and put it back when needed.